# What is the purpose of using !! in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know the purpose of using `!!` in JS.

For ex:

```
this.enabled = function (value) {
   if (arguments.length) {
    enabled = !!value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not related to angular

It's just a way to transform value to bool. ( according to truthy/falsy values)

There is a lot of articles about it.

examples :

`!!"a"` //true

`!!"0"` //true

`!!0` //false

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, this question has nothing to do with AngularJS--it is a JS syntax question.

The purpose of `!!` in JavaScript (and other langs) is to force a value to boolean.

Using a single `!` forces it to boolean, but opposite of whether the value was "truthy" or "falsy". The second `!` flips it back to be a boolean which matches the original "truthy" or "falsy" evaluation.

```
var a = 'a string';
var f = !a; // f is now boolean false because a was "truthy:
var t = !!a; // f is now boolean true because a was "truthy:
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific to Angular, it serves to transform a non-boolean value like `undefined` to boolean.